# Compiling Qt Multimedia for Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, qtonpi

Thanks for taking a look, now to business.

I've set up a cross compile env for my Raspberry Pi following [this guide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide).

I have been able to port most of my application so far, but I'm running up against some very weird things when trying to compile the multimedia plugin.

1. During configure, using the mounted image, it fails to find gstreamer development files, which is understood because they dont come part of the standard image. 
   So, I shifted installing the dev packages, then mounting the sdcard to use as my sysroot so the dev packages would be found. And they are. During configure. When it comes time to compile QtMultimedia, all I get is the audio plugin.
2. When I investigate, it seems to fail to locate `gst/gst.h`, a file which I can verify is on the system. I have done everything from hardcoding the paths to just screaming at it, but I cannot for the life of me figure out whats going wrong. 
   Even more painful, the video plugin works out of the box so to speak on my desktop version of Qt5. All of the compilation errors seem to relate to not being able to find headers, even though it does find them during ./configure.

I'm really at my wits end with this and any advice or insights into the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it is possible to send the raspbian image so we can see whats going on?

Comment: Can you give us the error messages?